# How to change a VARCHAR value with two digit in a column (eg: 0214 month year) to a date format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Additional:

```
(DATE(VALUE('20'+RIGHT(REPORT_MONTHANDYEAR__C ,2)) , VALUE(LEFT(REPORT_MONTHANDYEAR__C, IF( LEN(REPORT_MONTHANDYEAR__C) = 3 , 1, 2)))
```

This is how I want to change using formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('0214','%m%Y')
```

Or get right date (1st) -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01', '0214'),'%d%m%Y')
=> 01.02.2014
```

Comment: @BalaMani: please accept this answer. To do so, find the tick mark to the left of it, and click it so it turns green. This marks the question as resolved, and rewards the person who helped you with a few points for their time and effort.